# Apparently, CLLocation objects cannot be archived / unarchived precisely

Tags: ios, unit-testing, cllocation, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

In my app (only relevant code shown), I have a class `Test` with a property

```
var location: CLLocation
```

I archive it using

```
public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(location, forKey: "location")
}
```

And it is unarchived using

```
required convenience public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let unarchivedLocation = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "location") as! CLLocation
    self.init(location: unarchivedLocation)
}
```

Unit testing is done using

```
func test_archiningUnarchiving() {
    // given
    let location = CLLocation.init(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
    let test = Test(location: location)
    // when
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: test)
    let unarchivedTest = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? Test
    // then
    XCTAssertEqual(unarchivedTest!.location, location, "location was not correctly unarchived")
}
```

This test fails:

```
XCTAssertEqual failed: ("<+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/19/18, 3:30:50 PM Central European Standard Time") is not equal to ("<+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/19/18, 3:30:50 PM Central European Standard Time") - location was not correctly unarchived
```

The log shows twice exactly the same data for the original and the unarchived location.
Any idea what could have gone wrong anyway??

Comment: Am I incorrect in thinking you are comparing a CLLocation with a ShoppingLocation in the test?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I simplified the code and forgot to edit this. I will edit my question, and thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Try `let x = CLLocation(); let y = x.copy() as! CLLocation; XCTAssertEqual(x, y);`. That fails, too. It may be far more basic question than just encoding. I wager it's falling back to `NSObject` `isEqual` method that only returns true if they point to the same instance.

Comment: @Rob Do you think I should submit a bug report?

Comment: They're likely to dismiss a "bug" report because it appears to work as documented. But perhaps an "enhancement" request...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not archiving, but rather the equality test. If you compare two different `CLLocation` instances, even if they're identical, it will always return `false`.

Bottom line, any `NSObject` subclass that doesn't explicitly implement `isEqual:` (such as is the case with `CLLocation`) will experience this behavior.

The [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C: Interacting with Objective-C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35) says:

> Swift provides default implementations of the `==` and `===` operators and adopts the `Equatable` protocol for objects that derive from the `NSObject` class. The default implementation of the `==` operator invokes the `isEqual:` method ... You should not override the equality or identity operators for types imported from Objective-C.

And, the [Concepts in Objective-C Programming: Introspection](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introspection/Introspection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH9-SW1) tells us:

> The default `NSObject` implementation of `isEqual:` simply checks for pointer equality.

Personally, I wish that `NSObject` subclasses didn't automatically inherit `isEqual:`, but it is what it is.

Bottom line, don't attempt to test for equality of `NSObject` subclasses unless you know it has properly implemented `isEqual:` override. If you want, write your own method, e.g. `isEqual(to location: CLLocation)` (but not `isEqual(_:)`) that performs memberwise comparison of two `CLLocation` objects.

Comment: Thanks, Rob, I was not aware of this!